# ctypes, function returning pointer to a structure

Tags: python, ctypes

My C code is returning a pointer to the structure, this is how I have defined it in `python`

```
class CONTEXT(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = [
                ("sockfd", ctypes.c_int), 
                ("eidSeq", ctypes.c_longlong)
             ]
# API
# connect
PY_connect=NativeDll.gf_connect
# connect input and output parameter declaration
PY_connect.argtype = [ 
                          ctypes.c_char_p, 
                          ctypes.c_char_p, 
                          ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
                        ]
PY_connect.restype = [
                          ctypes.POINTER(CONTEXT)
                        ]
```

But I am getting following error for the `restype`

`TypeError: restype must be a type, a callable, or None`

Comment: Purely guessing here, but I would suggest that restype should just be a plain type, rather than the list of types which you currently have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As DaveP already correctly guessed in comments, `restype` must not be a list of types.

```
PY_connect.restype = ctypes.POINTER(CONTEXT)
```

Note also that argument types are set by the `argtypes` attribute, not `argtype`.

Comment: I am getting _type_ must have storage info

Comment: @KonstantinosMonachopoulos Perhaps you typed `pointer` instead of `POINTER`